# Android: Pressing a button to reset the activity at a fast rate crashes the program

Tags: android, button, android-activity, crash, onclicklistener

I have a button set to reset the activity. When I press it too fast too many times, it not only queues up the activity (as in when I press back, there is another instance of the activity) and can crash. Is there anything I can do to prevent these things from happening?

The code I'm using in the onClick method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: why you are using intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); what is the purpose.

Comment: I think you should disable the button click after clicked for first time, and enable it later. So the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: I use it to disable the animation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                btn.setEnabled(false);
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

or just simply use

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        //your code here
        btn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **try/catch** to be sure any crash does not happen and also you can use **recreate()** method to restart your activity:

```
   try{
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               button.setEnabled(false);

                recreate();

               button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e ){
        Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
    }
```